# Please explain why this isomorphic class has 30 graphs and 4 automorphisms

Tags: graph-theory

[image: Iso class]

Please explain why this iso class with 5 vertices and edges has 30 graphs and 4 automorphisms.
I understand there are 5 ways to choose a, but then where does 4 choose 2 come in? Please help. This is killing me.

Comment: 4 choose 2 comes from picking either the two non-$a$ vertices that are connected to each other, or (equivalently) the two non-$a$ vertices that aren't connected to each other.  If you think about the classes of vertices a bit, you should see where the automorphisms come from...

Comment: Thank you very much that makes sense, but how do i get the automorphisms? Also how many graphs are there of a 5 deg and vertices iso class with the degree sequence 32221?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An automorphism is an isomorphism from a graph to itself. There can only be one possible mapping for $a \in V(G)$, and that is to itself. Now, $b, c$ are adjacent to each other. So we can swap their ordering, as they are both distance $1$ from $a$; and they are both distance $2$ from the other graph. Similarly, we can map $d, e$ in two possible ways. So we have:

$a \to a$ 
$b \to b, c$ 
$c \to b, c$ 
$d \to d, e$ 
$e \to d, e$

And so we have four automorphisms.

Comment: Thank you very much. Also why does the number of automorphism times the number of isomorphic graph equal 120? Is that number significant?

Comment: I see no significance in that number.

Comment: I might add as well that graph isomorphisms and automorphisms are algebraic groups. So by Lagrange's theorem, we have that the number of automorphisms divides the number of isomorphisms on $G$.

Comment: Thank you very much that means that the total number of graphs should be 120? But shouldn't the total number of graphs be (5 choose 2) choose 5) since there are 5 vertices and edges?

Comment: No. My last comment was just a direct application of Lagrange's Theorem. The automorphism group is a subgroup of the isomorphism group. Steven Stadnicki's comment answered your question about the number of graphs.